# Facebook c# Access user wall information

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I want to get the wall information of a user and analyse it. It is a public information but when I try I will always get a `403` error.

Why?

1. Do I need to register my app in facebook even though I am not posting any info?
2. Do it need login infomation? If yes: How to provide that information?

Comment: are you not happy with that answer?

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes
2. Use [Facebook Connect](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web) on your site